# fwrite with non ASCII characters

Tags: c, windows, fwrite, non-ascii-characters

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char* alpha = "Ω";
  fwrite(alpha, 1, strlen(alpha), stdout);
  return 0;
}
```

On Windows I get the following output:

```
��
```

I tried changing the line to this:

```
char* alpha = "zΩ";
```

and it prints correctly. The output is encoded correctly, just not printing
correctly:

```
$ bad | od -tx1c
0000000  ce  a9
        316 251

$ good | od -tx1c
0000000  7a  ce  a9
          z 316 251
```

How can I use fwrite with non ASCII as the first character?

To response to some comments: The source file is correctly formatted as UTF-8, and my code page is also correctly set as UTF-8:

```
$ chcp.com
Active code page: 65001
```

Comment: Call `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT)` and then write a `wchar_t *` wide-character string using `fwrite`. Since the underlying CRT file is in UTF-16 mode and is a console, the write is implemented by calling the Unicode API `WriteConsoleW`.

Comment: This works for me: `wchar_t *alpha = L"Ω";` `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);` `fwrite(alpha, 2, wcslen(alpha), stdout);`

Comment: {0xa9, 0x03} is little-endian UTF-16 for "Ω", i.e. U+03A9. Are you using a plain Windows console to run this or running in a POSIX shell that pipes to a pty implementation of some kind? Check `GetFileType(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE))`. Is it `FILE_TYPE_CHAR` (2, a console buffer handle) or `FILE_TYPE_PIPE` (3)?

Comment: I built it using VS 2015, just using the simple command `cl good.c`, and tested in Windows 7 and 10 (the latest Windows has a new console, but unfortunately there are still some problems with codepage 65001). If you're building with MinGW, `fwrite` might not work the same. Try the community edition of VS 2015.

Comment: @eryksun I am using `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe`. Thank you for your help, but I am not interested in using Visual Studio

Comment: Well, if it's calling `WriteFile` instead of `WriteConsoleW`, then this won't work. Sorry. If `_setmode` succeeds, try calling `wprintf` or `fwprintf`.

Comment: You can set a breakpoint on `kernel32!WriteConsoleW`. I use Microsoft's [Debugging tools for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551063) that come with the SDK.

Comment: @eryksun but this doesnt explain why `zΩ` works

Comment: I think in this case the problem with writing just Ω as the UTF-8 string `"\xce\xa9"` is that `fwrite` is flushing its buffer on writing the first byte. To my knowledge splitting a multibyte-character string across writes is only supported for DBCS in East-Asian locales, not UTF-8. (Actually Microsoft's CRT has special support for DBCS when the locale isn't the default C locale.) So the console tries to decode `"\xce"` and `"\xa9"` as two separate UTF-8 strings. If you add an initial `"z"` byte, then probably `"\xce\xa9"` gets written in a single call to `WriteFile`.

Comment: Even if it's written in a single pass, there will be additional problems with codepage 65001. In this case, prior to Windows 8 the console will report back to `WriteFile` the number of UTF-16 characters it wrote instead of the number of bytes. This leads to erroneously retrying partial writes since the caller sees that apparently not all of the buffer was written. This stems from an assumption of one byte per ANSI character. I think it's special-cased for DBCS in East-Asian locales, but nothing is done for UTF-8. This problem (but not all codepage 65001 problems) is fixed in Windows 8+.

Comment: If it's not clear in context, conhost.exe uses `wchar_t` strings internally. So if you call `WriteConsoleA` or `WriteFile` to write to the screen buffer, the current codepage is used to decode the byte string as a UTF-16 string. Note that the console window is limited to the Unicode BMP (UCS-2) since it uses one `wchar_t` code per character cell. It doesn't decode UTF-16 surrogate pairs as a single code point / glyph. Also, to my knowledge the console window isn't able to mix single-width and double-width (typically CJK) glyphs for the selected font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows `fwrite` calls `WriteFile` internally, in this case incorrectly. My
solution was to just call `WriteFile` directly:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
  char* alpha = "Ω";
  DWORD bravo;
  WriteFile(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), alpha, strlen(alpha), &bravo, 0);
  return 0;
}
```

- [Win32 Equivalents for C Run-Time Functions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/99456)
- [WriteFile function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa365747)

Comment: In general you need `lpNumberOfBytesWritten`. What if stdout is a pipe? For example, "[w]hen writing to a non-blocking, byte-mode pipe handle with insufficient buffer space, `WriteFile` returns `TRUE` with `*lpNumberOfBytesWritten < nNumberOfBytesToWrite`". However, when the target is a console buffer `lpNumberOfBytesWritten` is only correct in Windows 8+. In Windows 7 it erroneously returns the number of UTF-16 codes written. So you'll need to handle the case where stdout is a console separately, which probably in that case you can ignore `lpNumberOfBytesWritten`.

Comment: If you need a separate code path for a console anyway, you may as well decode the UTF-8 to UTF-16 yourself and call `WriteConsoleW` . When stdout isn't a console you can just use `fwrite`.

Comment: I have to stress that codepage 65001 in the console is broken. Try pasting non-ASCII Unicode into the console and try to read it via `ReadFile`. It gets encoded to the console codepage using `WideCharToMultiByte` using a temporary buffer that's sized for ANSI, i.e. 1 byte per `wchar_t` character. This fails for UTF-8 given non-ASCII characters. But conhost.exe doesn't handle this by resizing the temporary buffer. It just ignores the failure and returns that it 'successfully' read 0 bytes. There's nothing you can do about it. Even Windows 10 still has this bug.